# Not readable messages LogCat Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logging, logcat

I am trying to debug a mobile application written in java and Eclipse appears some messages with "?" for Time, PID, Application and Tag columns. Does anybody know what may be the problem?

[image: relative screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be a good idea to post some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. I just uploaded a screenshot with the problem.

Comment: Screenshots are best avoided, and the gui itself is an additional source of potential problems (for example if you have more than one open, there at least used to be conflicts).  Please post some of the *textual* output of the `adb logcat` command in a terminal window on your machine.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "textual output"? It is thousands of lines and it is becoming even verbose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is requesting that you run `adb logcat` and copy and paste a few lines from the output. You don't need to post the whole thing, just enough to show that the problem is occurring there as well.

Comment: Actually, if I squint at the screenshot above, it looks like this information is present, but not being parsed by the gui into columns.  Perhaps there's a version incompatibility between the ADT and the device?

Comment: The output of adb logcat is expected (without question marks). There may be kind of incompatibility between ADT and the device. Thank you!